# VBA Excel - Function - length of array

Tags: excel, vba

i found multiple times this function for determining the length of an array.
It doesn't work for me...
Anyone knows the solution?

```
Function GetArrayLength(arr As Variant) As Integer

   If IsEmpty(arr) Then

      GetArrayLength = 0

   Else

      GetArrayLength = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1

   End If

End Function
```

If i try to use the function in excel then, it's not working...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5dDL.png)

Can you tell me what might be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a range - which is two-dimensional array.
Change your input parameter:

```vb
Function GetArrayLength(rg As Range) As Long
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = rg.Value

   If IsEmpty(arr) Then
      GetArrayLength = 0
      
   ElseIf rg.Cells.Count = 1 Then
     GetArrayLength = 1
     
   Else
      GetArrayLength = UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1) + 1
      
   End If

End Function
```

But you could use a `=ROWS(A1:A5)` to achieve the same result without a UDF